# Discrete math three fundamental principles

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose that there are 15 identical copies of The Great Gastby and 12 distinct biographies on a bookshelf.

(a) How many different selections of 12 books are possible?
(b) How many different selections of 10 books are possible?

I figured out (a)

$ 2 ^{12} = 4096$

But I'm stuck on b.

I tried $ 2^{10} = 1024$ but thats not the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find the ways of picking books, you're counting the number of ways to pick $k$ biographies at a time, as the other books are identical. So, in the first case this is

$$
\sum_{k=0}^{12}{12\choose k}=2^{12}=4096
$$

In the second case, it isn't possible to pick $12$ or $11$ of the biographies, so we subtract these choices off:

$$
4096-{12\choose 12}-{12\choose 11}=4096-1-12=4083
$$

Which is the answer in the second case.

Comment: I'm confused, why do you subtract it by 12. You have 2 choices to choose from the biographies or the great gatsby which is where I got the 2^12.

Comment: $12$ is the number of ways of picking $11$ of the biographies. We're counting ways of picking $10$ books, so we should definitely not count these ways of picking the biographies. Note that if you pick $k$ biographies the remaining $10-k$ books are identical copies of *The Great Gatsby* and so are uniquely determined.

Comment: In your answer you modeled the 15 identical books as the same book. There's an important distinction that this misses. We can pick multiple copies of *The Great Gatsby*. They are identical but we can still choose more than one of them. Your solution does not count cases in which we've picked *The Great Gatsby* multiple times at all.